# IntelliJ: How to search in previous search results

Tags: intellij-idea

Does Intellij allow you to search in previous search results? I can't seem to find anything about it. Might be possible with a custom scope?

Comment: After some search I didn`t find anything as well. I even searched for a plugin but nothing there too.

Comment: Weird because it would add a lot of power/flexibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search in previous search results, you need have a search result open in the Find tool window. Then the scope `Files in Previous Search Result` appears in `Find in Path` and `Find Usages Settings`:
[image: Find Usages Settings dialog]

Comment: Are you sure this is present in IntelliJ (2019.1.3)?

Comment: I just tested 2019.1.4 and it is available.

Comment: Ah, found it! Reasonably intuitive once you know it's there